# How to pass a reference button from v-btn onclick method?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-btn and I want to pass the v-btn reference to on-click method so I can control the loading field in the method.  This is my v-btn code and is passed a event right now for testing:

```
 <v-btn v-on:click="updateService($event, service)"
   :loading="updatingService" class="mr-4">

 updateService: function(event, service) {
   console.log("update service, event: ", event.source, ", service: ", service);
   //I want to do following:
   btn.loading = true
   //after some api call
   btn.loading = false
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v-btn has a loading prop. You just need to define updatingService in your data and toggle it.

in your data:

```
data() {
  return {
    updatingService: false,
  }
}
```

and change your function to:

```
 updateService: function(event, service) {
   console.log("update service, event: ", event.source, ", service: ", service);
   //I want to do following:
   this.updatingService = true
   //after some api call
   this.updatingService = false
 }
```

It is the best practice. Any way you can use ref prop:

```
 <v-btn ref="theBtn" v-on:click="updateService($event, service)"
   :loading="updatingService" class="mr-4">
```

then

```
 updateService: function(event, service) {
   console.log("update service, event: ", event.source, ", service: ", service);
   //I want to do following:
   this.$refs.theBtn.loading = true
   //after some api call
   this.$refs.theBtn.loading = false
 }
```